# Using mysqli_escape_string error

Tags: php, mysqli

How come I kept receiving this  errror when I am using this mysqli_real_escape_string()?

```
mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\beatbeast\reg.php on line 6
```

I already pass the connection, and the strings that are needed to be sanitize, but how come i keep on getting that error?

here's my code

```
<?php
    class Db_DatabaseUtilities{

        public static function registerAccount($conn,$username,$password,$email){
            if(!isset($conn)){
                    echo"XDDDDDDDDD";
            }
            $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$username);
            $email =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$username);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$password);
            $hashedpass = crypt($password,$username);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO accounts ('username','password','email') VALUES('{$username}','{$hashedpass}','{$email}')";
            Db_DatabaseUtilities::perform_query($conn, $sql);
        }

        public static function perform_query($conn,$sql){
            $result_set = $conn->query($sql);
            if(!$result_set){
                die("Die Database Query Failed");
            }else{
                return $result_set;
            }
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

first: if this is your real code you are escaping `$username` twice and `$email` not at all:

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$username);
$email =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$username);//should probably be $email as second param
```

you have an option of two problems:

1. you have a bad database connection...*check your connection and make sure it has the encoding* set.
2. you have bad input data...*one of your parameters may not be a valid string*

I can't see any other options...
Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Check the line 6 of `reg.php`.

`string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )`

You need to pass the mysqli connection as the first parameter.

Comment: echo"XDDDDDDDDD"; that's line 6

Comment: @user962206 Is the file `reg.php` ? line 6 don't have `mysqli_real_escape_string `